# How to apply the "chrome.webnavigation.oncommitted.addlistener" in this case?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension, which changes the colors in the images of the web pages. When the extension is activated (via a icon on the Chrome browser toolbar ), the images in all open pages in tabs are recolored . When the URL of a tab is updated, the images are then recolored too. But, before show the recolored images, there are shown the original.
Inorder to solve it, I hide the document (via the "esconde.js"). Then call "recolor.js" which makes changes in the images and finally, it is injected the "mostra.js", that makes the document visible. 
With this code, it was supposed that the document was visible only after the images are recolored, since the script "mostra.js" is a callback script " recolor.js " . I do not know why it does not happen as expected, ecause in most of pages I still see the original images before the recolored.
I read a few things , and I think that (perhaps) with "chrome.webnavigation.oncommitted.addlistener" instead of "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener" it could solve.
However, I don't know how to substitute the "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener" by "chrome.webnavigation.oncommitted.addlistener" (although it basic). 
Please can someone help me in this task ?

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
  if (flag){
    if (info.status != "complete") 
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"esconde.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
    if (info.status == "complete") {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"recolor.js", runAt: 'document_start' }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"mostra.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
      });
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded would be more appropriate for the task:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, ...)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with arrow functions (supported by most of the modern browsers) and filters:

```
'use strict';
console.log('RUNNING ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());

chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(details => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, { file: "content/login.js" }, (resultsArray) => {
        console.table(resultsArray);
    });
}, {
    url: [
        { pathSuffix: 'login.aspx' }
    ]
});
```